# My app background won't fill the screen

Tags: android, layout, imageview

How do I make the background image fill the screen? I have tried several different suggestions and nothing seems to work.

[image]

Below is the code for my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andrewvanpeter.upandaway.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_flat_720x1280" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution :**

You can put the `layout_width` and the `layout_height` of your `ImageView` to `match_parent` :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_flat_720x1280" />
```

---

**Second solution :**

You can set the background directly in the `ConstraintLayout` (and don't forget to delete the `ImageView`) :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_flat_720x1280"
    tools:context="com.andrewvanpeter.upandaway.MainActivity">
```

Comment: The match_parent solution did not work; maybe I'm doing something else wrong. However, setting the background directly did work. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, it's a pleasure! Maybe you have a padding or margin somewhere... Or you have to fit the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

You can also to set the scaletype of imageview to fitXY like this :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_flat_720x1280" />
```